# I click "Save as.." in Photoshop CS5 / CS6 and nothing happens - using a netbook

Tags: windows-xp, photoshop-cs5, photoshop-cs6

I'm using Windows XP, with a low resourceful netbook (Exomate X352, a not-international brand, or you can call it as a generic brand).

The problem is, I can do everything in [Adobe Photoshop CS5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop#CS5) or [CS6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop#CS6) (including the basic save), but to use the "Save as.." option. When I click it, nothing pops-up. It is only available the first time I save it.

Comment: This is for people who find the page via googling, and they're having this issue on a NEWER version of Photoshop (in my case CC 2015.5)

In my case it wasn't the same problem as OP had (netbook resolution), it was apparently just out of memory. I have 100 undo levels and was using lots of history brush when it happened. I couldn't get a "save" or "save as" dialogue on any open document. Even new ones. 

What DID work was File - Export As... - choose the default PNG. I got a 32-bit PNG with transparency so definitely no quality loss. I then restarted PS and everything's OK again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the reason and the solution to this problem:

Since CS5, Adobe chose to not show the **Save As..** window since its resolution is bigger than the native resolution of many netbooks (1024x600). That's why the Adobe CS5 *minimum requirements* specify the **1024x768** resolution too.

I've been using my [Google-fu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu), and many solutions were only for specified netbooks (Acer, Nvidia/AMD related netbooks, and Dell), but this one in particular is for EVERY netbook that isn't capable of choosing a higher resolution than 1024x600:

1. Go to your Desktop, Right click to the background and choose Properties.
2. Enter to the Configuration tag → Advanced options button
3. Untick the "hide the modes that this monitor can't show" option (My Windows is in Spanish, you may know what I mean :D).
4. Apply, accept.

And there you go, now you can specify your resolution! (1024x768 in my case).

Comment: Oh wow I wrote unconsiously bad. Thanks for the corrections Peter!